# Роутер постоянно отключает интернет

Tags: wifi, роутер

У меня есть роутер tp-link archer c20. И он по нескольку раз в день отключает интернет. Т.е wi-fi работает, а доступа к интернету нет. Проблему решаю так: несколько раз включаю и отключают аунтефикацию. Это жутко бесит. Уже пробовал обновлять прошивку, чего только не пробовал, а он опять за своё. Стоит покупать новый или проблема решаема другими способами?

Comment: Причин может быть множество. У меня ноут часто терял соединение в роутером из-за неустановленных родных драйверов wi-fi (установленные по умолчанию виндой оказались неподходящими). Также были частые разрывы соединения по причине поврежденного кабеля: проблема была решена, когда провайдер поменял кабель.

Comment: Нет и остальных компов тоже инет отваливается. И драйвер я тоже обновлял

Answer (score 2):

Проблема связана именно с ошибками в прошивке.

Так как Ваш роутер поддерживается прошивкой [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BModel*%7E%5D=Archer+C20), то перед задуманой вами покупкой другого устройства, попробуйте её.

**Внимание** так как вы не указали версию устройства, обратите пристальное внимание на список по ссылке и выберите нужное.